# Best Way to call external program in c# and parse output

Tags: c#, .net

#### Duplicate

> [Redirect console output to textbox in separate program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415620/redirect-console-output-to-textbox-in-separate-program-c)
> [Capturing nslookup shell output with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353601/capturing-nslookup-shell-output-with-c)

I am looking to call an external program from within my c# code.

The program I am calling, lets say foo.exe returns about 12 lines of text.

I want to call the program and parse thru the output.

What is the most optimal way to do this ?

Code snippet also appreciated :)

Thank You very much.

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/353601/capturing-nslookup-shell-output-with-c

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class RedirectingProcessOutput
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c dir *.cs";
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.Start();

        string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        p.WaitForExit();

        Console.WriteLine("Output:");
        Console.WriteLine(output);    
    }
}
```

Comment: Almost.  You need to call WaitForExit() after ReadToEnd(), to avoid blocking issues.

Comment: Just did that since the answer worked for me with that correction

Comment: I am not so sure about the interaction (and order) of `ReadToEnd` and `WaitForExit`. For example, read [here](http://multipleinheritance.wordpress.com/2012/07/31/process-waitforexit-and-exited-event-arent-working/).

Comment: In longer programs, remember to dispose the process or use it in a `using(Process pProcess = new Process()) { }` block