# How To Run A Downloaded File From Memory?

Tags: c#, download, arrays, webclient, exe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Load an EXE file and run it from memory using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553875/load-an-exe-file-and-run-it-from-memory-using-c-sharp)

I am using the WebClient class to download a .exe from a web server. Is there a way that I can run the .exe without saving it to disk first?

For the purpose of completeness let me show you what I have so far.

Here is the code I use to start the download:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadDataCompleted += new DownloadDataCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadDataCompleted);
webClient.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri("http://www.somewebsite.com/calc.exe"));
```

And in the (webClient_DownloadDataCompleted) method I simply grab the bytes from the parameter e:

```
private void webClient_DownloadDataCompleted(object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Byte[] downloadedData = e.Result;
    // how to run this like a .exe?
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure. My program cannot make any assumptions about the type of .exe.

Comment: Generic case is covered by duplicate with explanation why you have to store and run from disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `.exe` is a .NET program, you can [load an assembly and run its entry point](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5837958/458193).

Otherwise, while [there are ways to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/305319/458193), I can't see the problem with saving a file in temporary directory and running it from there which is so much less painful.

Comment: Yes. Saving it to the system temp directory is probably what I will end up doing.

Comment: @Jan: If you have such option, definitely go with it. Running an arbitrary PE file is no easy thing as you can see.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this thread. I think you can solve it with `VirtualAlloc`

[Is it possible to execute an x86 assembly sequence from within C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959087/is-it-possible-to-execute-an-x86-assembly-sequence-from-within-c/959144#959144)

If your byte array contains a .Net assembly you should be able to do this:

```
Assembly assembly = AppDomain.Load(byteArray)
Type typeToExecute = assembly.GetType("ClassName");
Object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeToExecute);
```