# Return a value to external invoker C++

Tags: c#, c++, exe

I am invoking a C/C++ program (exe) from C#, I want to return a float value from my C/C++ to the C# code, I have the exe code which writes file a for a single value, instead I want to return that value to C#. How can I do that?

Comment: How are you invoking it?

Comment: Using "Process", i.e. Process.Start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could output the result of your C/C++ program to the standard output, and then parse it with C# after the invokation.

Check this answer: [Best Way to call external program in c# and parse output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878632/best-way-to-call-external-program-in-c-and-parse-output)

Or if your program is called a lot a time, maybe a better solution would be to let it run and communicate with your C# program through local sockets. C# program may send request by network and get the result back.

Answer (score 0):

If that code writes a float to a file, then all you can do is read the file afterwards.

Comment: I cannot afford disk space. This exe needs to run hundreds of times at any give instant.