# c# load C file and then convert it to Assembly

Tags: c#, c, assembly

(C#) I would like to load a C file using windows form then convert it into assembly language and shows it on a rich text box. Is it possible to do on C#? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question does not follow StakOverflow rules. Before posting, take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: as long as you can find a dll that can convert it

Answer (score 2):

In the [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) application you can achieve this by following steps

1. Load the .c file
2. Compile it with `cl.exe`.
3. Use the `dumpbin.exe` utility to disasmble the output exe file
4. Show the result in Rich Text box

You'll need `System.Diagnostics.Process` class to urn those utilities. See example on [Best Way to call external program in c# and parse output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878632/best-way-to-call-external-program-in-c-sharp-and-parse-output)

Comment: +1 for introducing me to one more disassembler!

Comment: new for me. thank you for giving me a guide