# Write single variable (or set of variables) of R script to stdout for calling C# code

Tags: c#, r

I have several R scripts that take in data (likely from arguments passed to `Rscript` or a bat file), chug through a calculation and at the end output either a list or vector of values (generically floats and strings). How can I output only these values to stdout (or whatever is appropriate) to the calling `C#` process without resorting to writing and reading files as a middle man?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best Way to call external program in c# and parse output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878632/best-way-to-call-external-program-in-c-sharp-and-parse-output)

Comment: Yup, that's the C# end of things, but there are R specific issues (like directing correctly to stdout and only outputting the necessary variables) that the linking question doesn't address.

Comment: How to print values to `stdout` in R would probably justify its own question (or a Google search). The title (and indeed body) of the question does not cover how to print from R.

Comment: Would you then be satisfied if I updated the title/body of this post to reflect that?

Comment: Done, see if you like that phrasing better?

Answer (score 0):

There are several options available to pass data in-memory between R and .NET/Mono or over a network pipe, without file I/O in-between. I'll mention a couple I am partial to, being respectively a contributor to, and author of,

- [R.NET](http://rdotnet.codeplex.com/) if the entry point is a program running on .NET or Mono, calling R. A new release is under development.
- the [rClr](http://rclr.codeplex.com/) package if R is the main process. Mirrored on a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/jmp75/rClr). The latest official binary release is available, at the time of writing, at [r2clr.codeplex.com](http://r2clr.codeplex.com/).