# Which format should be SSH private key for LibGit2 LibGit2Sharp (+SSH)

Tags: .net, git, ssh, libgit2, libgit2sharp-ssh

I´m kind of stuck with an SSH private key issue and LibGit2Sharp-Ssh.

I have a .Net/C# application that uses LibGit2Sharp-Ssh to clone a Git repository.

I need to use SSH (https with user/password is not an option) and I also have a valid key, which is already working e.g. with Teamcity.

My code looks like this:

```
CloneOptions options = new CloneOptions
{
     Checkout = false,
     CredentialsProvider = (url, user, cred) => new SshUserKeyCredentials()
     {
          PrivateKey = privateKey,
          Passphrase = passphrase,
          PublicKey = publicKey,
          Username = "git"
     }
};
var clone = LibGit2Sharp.Repository.Clone(remoteUrl, localPath, options);
```

`privateKey` points to a private key file in "OpenSSH" format.

When `Clone` is executed i get:

```
LibGit2Sharp.LibGit2SharpException: "Failed to authenticate SSH session: Invalid key data, not base64 encoded"
```

I've tried all of the private key formats I could create with PuttyGen, but I always get the same result.

What might be the issue or in what format do I need to create the private key file?

My OpenSSH-format key looks like (truncated):

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,27A4E70608469318

<Key-Data, like "sdhsdcQEHBg3uzfb...">
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: Is your library this one? https://github.com/leobuskin/libgit2sharp-ssh

Comment: Yes. I took it from NuGet

Comment: You said: "privateKey point to a private key file"...  to clarify, what do you mean when you say "key file"?  Is it the filename?  Or is it the _contents_ of the key?

Comment: It´s the abolute path to the private key file (OpenSSH-format)

Answer (score 4):

> privateKey point to a private key file in "OpenSSH" format.

`privateKey` needs to point to a *key*, not a *path* to a key.  You need to read the key file and place the contents into a `string` that you can pass to `privateKey`.

Comment: I just tried that, but not sure what the content of that string should be. PuttyGen offers different key formats. I used both "OpenSSH" as well as "OpenSSH (new format)". I took the files "as is", I truncated the content so "see" only the Base64 content... Allways same result saying "Invalid key data, not base64 encoded"...

Comment: I don't think this is true, the docs say: "Private key file location for SSH authentication". Besides if you put in an actual key you get the error `Failed to authenticate SSH session: Unable to open public key file
`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating your private key with PuttyGen (`ppk` keys), Use PuttyGen to load said `ppk` file, and save it as OpenSSH file (`id_rsa`, `id_rsa.pub`)

Or, as I described here, use Git for Windows PATH to access ssh-keygen, and create one directly with the right format:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "key for my Git repo server" -q -P ""
```

Comment: Maybe my first post was a bit misleading: that´s what i did. I used PuttyGen to convert the ppk into different formats, including OpenSSH-export

Comment: @emvoll Then you need to use that openssh private key (open it to check it is indeed in base 64 encoded (PEM format, as in http://blog.oddbit.com/2011/05/08/converting-openssh-public-keys/)

Comment: It pretty much does. Only difference is that there seems to be some header on top of the key data. I´ll post the "frame" without the key-data below (formatting seems not to be working here...)

Comment: Note: I see that error message in implementations like https://github.com/uchida/pandora_agent_win32/blob/76e06b6358581859e4e8b88d80ddbe67b6e02b9a/ssh/libssh2/userauth.c#L303-L304, using https://github.com/uchida/pandora_agent_win32/blob/76e06b6358581859e4e8b88d80ddbe67b6e02b9a/ssh/libssh2/misc.c#L105-L169

Answer (score -1):

That´s how my OpenSSH-Key looks like (key data truncated):

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,27A4E70608469318

<Key-Data, like "sdhsdcQEHBg3uzfb...">
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Is there some way i can verify tha exported key?

Comment: You can edit your question, no need to add an "answer" which is not one.

Comment: You should delete this answer.