# Azure DevOps, how to get the blobIds

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am trying to download a blobbed zip for a repository on the Azure DevOps Server 2019 API using the following documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/blobs/get%20blobs%20zip?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0

The request body is supposed to contain:

```
REQUEST BODY
Name    Type     Description
body    string[] Blob IDs (SHA1 hashes) to be returned in the zip file.
```

How can I obtain the blob ids?

Comment: The blobs are SHA1 hashes of files that you want to download. Look at the other available APIs to determine how to retrieve a list of files with associated hashes.

Comment: Hi @DanielMann is there a way to download the whole repository, basically the zip file you can download from the DevOps repo page?

Comment: Why can't you just do git clone --mirror to clone a copy of the repo?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I will have a look at that. I assumed I could download a zip file containing the whole  solution, I did that when I was using the vstfs api. But Git is different doing a clone programatically is possibly the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I obtain the blob ids?

You can try [Items-List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/items/list?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0#full-recursion-and-with-content-metadata) api to obtain the blob ids:

```
GET https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/items?recursionLevel=Full&api-version=5.0
```

The response:

[image]

Also, if you're trying to get the IDs programatically, you can use [GitHttpClientBase.GetItemsAsync Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.sourcecontrol.webapi.githttpclientbase.getitemsasync?view=azure-devops-dotnet#Microsoft_TeamFoundation_SourceControl_WebApi_GitHttpClientBase_GetItemsAsync_System_Guid_System_Guid_System_String_System_Nullable_Microsoft_TeamFoundation_SourceControl_WebApi_VersionControlRecursionType__System_Nullable_System_Boolean__System_Nullable_System_Boolean__System_Nullable_System_Boolean__System_Nullable_System_Boolean__Microsoft_TeamFoundation_SourceControl_WebApi_GitVersionDescriptor_System_Object_System_Threading_CancellationToken_)
.

Ps: As **Daniel** commented above, it's more recommended to use git command to download whole repository. So you can also try to call git-related api in your code if you want to do that programatically. There're many discussions online about this topic, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432245/is-there-some-way-to-work-with-git-using-net-application).(Since it's not your original question about Blobids, I won't talk too much here.)