# How to download a raw file from GitHub in C# .NET

Tags: c#, webclient

I am trying to use the `DownloadFile` method of the `System.Net.WebClient` class to download files from GitHub. I tried downloading a `.txt` file from [here](https://github.com/github/platform-samples/blob/master/LICENSE.txt), and the result was [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WfBw.png). That's clearly the HTML code of the page, not the file. Tried googling some solutions, none of them worked. Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;

namespace download_file_test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                wc.Headers.Add("a", "a");
                try
                {
                    wc.DownloadFile("https://github.com/github/platform-samples/blob/master/LICENSE.txt", @"C:/Users/User/Desktop/test/test.txt");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }
                Console.ReadKey();
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code downloads the HTML of the GitHub page, not the file that it displays.

Try to download the [raw version instead](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/platform-samples/master/LICENSE.txt) by using `raw.githubusercontent.com` as domain and removing the `blob` part from it:

```cs
wc.DownloadFile("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/platform-samples/master/LICENSE.txt", @"C:/Users/User/Desktop/test/test.txt");
```

Comment: It worked! However, how could I download a `.zip` file using this method?

Comment: Prefixing `raw.` and removing `blob` prompts me to download the file

Comment: @Zamdie [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769032/how-do-i-download-zip-file-in-c) should help you to get on track. But honestly, it might be better off to simply clone the repository. Having `git` as dependency might be alright for your program. If you are using .NET Core, you can look at [LibGit2Sharp](https://edi.wang/post/2019/3/26/operate-git-with-net-core). Otherwise, please take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432245/is-there-some-way-to-work-with-git-using-net-application).

Comment: @Zamdie It might prompts you in the browser, because your browser doesn't handle the content type properly. It should work in your code nonetheless.