# How to get output of cmd in c# and dotnet

Tags: c#, .net

I try to send commend to cmd and get output. I'm sure it sent but I cannot get the output.

```
 ProcessStartInfo startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startinfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\mehmetcan\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130917\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe";
        startinfo.Arguments = @"devices";
        startinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        startinfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        startinfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        // Note: declare process as a variable in the class as it needs to be used in the event handlers
        process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo = startinfo;
```

It returns : "123456 devices "
How can get it in a string?

Comment: Eg is available in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587415/how-to-capture-shell-command-output-in-c .

Answer (score 1):

You should read it via

```
string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Doesnt work. It says : Cannot convert method group 'ReadToEnd' to non-delegate type 'string'. Did you intend to invoke the method?
@Nickolay Olshevsky

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll