# How to use SFTP with .pem file in C#.net?

Tags: c#, shell, unix, sftp, permission-denied

Problem: **I am using C# .net platform to SFTP a file to remote host with a key file/.pem file and no password.**

**C#.net source code:**

```
ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "sh",
    Arguments = "upload.sh " + file
};
p.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.UseShellExecute = false;
p.CreateNoWindow = true;
Process proc1 = new Process();
proc1.StartInfo = p;
proc1.Start();
string result = proc1.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
log.InfoFormat(result);
```

**upload.sh:**

```
sftp -i testsftp-key testsftp@sftp.xxx-xxx.com
put  filename
```

here

1. testsftp-key     :.pem filename(key file),
2. testsftp         :username,
3. sftp.xxx-xxx.com :host address.
4. filename         :file to be uploaded

**File is not getting uploaded when exe is executed by rrot user/cronjob. Executing using non-root user like pi uploads the file.
Permissions are 777 for all.**

**Error**:

```
permission denied
```

How to solve this permission issue?

Comment: why are you not able to run the command what are the errors and what is the output

Comment: Is it possible that the upload.sh file is not located in the working directory of your application?

Comment: @Longoon12000 no it is located in the working dir. it runs when i run it manually. but not with cronjob

Comment: @BugFinder no errors. just the file wont upload

Comment: @SayanSen If you run something from cronjob it's not assuming that the working dir is where your app is, you have to set the working dir yourself (working dir **!=** directory where the program is located). Can you please post your cronjob line that is supposed to run the application?

Comment: @reboot sh /etc/init.d/connectcapture.sh >/home/pi/logs/cronlog 2>&1

Comment: connectcapture.sh contains : cd /home/pi/ConnectCapture

mono /home/pi/ConnectCapture/cometconnect.exe

exit 0

Comment: That seems fine as you're changing into the correct directory in your connectcapture.sh file. You're not getting any output in your cronlog file?

Comment: im not sure why you would have a c# app to run in a cronjob to just to trigger a couple of shell commands. why not just submit the script. However, crontab doesnt have your path variable .. this seems like a normal unix crontab issue

Comment: @BugFinder `crontab doesnt have your path variable` do you mean that it wouldn't find `sh`? @SayanSen can you try doing `@reboot /bin/sh /etc/init.d/connectcapture.sh [...]` instead?

Comment: there is often some element of path, but not your user path.. Easiest way crontab a  `set > /tmp/x` and compare it ..

Comment: Then how may i do sftp to a host using username and pem file in c#? this sftp will be a part of a bigger program thats why. @BugFinder

Comment: @SayanSen did you do the crontab set thing I suggested, have you tried putting full paths in to all items....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to this:

```
ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "sh",
    Arguments = "/home/pi/../upload.sh " + file
};
p.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.UseShellExecute = false;
p.CreateNoWindow = false;
Process proc1 = new Process();
proc1.StartInfo = p;
proc1.Start();
string result = "";
using (System.IO.StreamReader output = proc1.StandardOutput) 
{
    result = output.ReadToEnd();
}
string error = "";
using (System.IO.StreamReader output = proc1.StandardError)
{
    error = output.ReadToEnd();
}
log.InfoFormat("SFTP result: {0}", result);
log.InfoFormat("{0}", error);
```

I am capturing the redirected stdout and stderr using streamreader. Now i can see the script upload.sh being run successfully and uploading the file to the remote server as well.
I took help from here:
[How to capture Shell command output in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587415/how-to-capture-shell-command-output-in-c)