# How to Get IP Address by Other DNS in C#?

Tags: c#, dns

We can get the IP Address by Dns.GetHostEntry from domain name, and it's resolve by the default DNS from my computer.
Now I wanna resolve by other DNS like 8.8.8.8 , how can I do in C#?

Answer (score 1):

.Net framework doesn't have built in support for resolving DNS by specifying a specific DNS server.. You'd have to write your own custom code, probably around some win32 API like [DnsQueryEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447188(v=vs.85).aspx) to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can also launch nslookup programmatically and capture and parse its output [Capturing nslookup shell output with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353601/capturing-nslookup-shell-output-with-c-sharp)

The command you use will be

```
nslookup host-to-look-up 8.8.8.8
```